# Custom deleter in std::unique_ptr not called

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Example does not make sense but still cannot explain why custom deleter is **not** called.

After the answers I got, I edited my code so `myP` is not null before `smartP` goes out of scope

```
int * myP = NULL;

{ 
   std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> smartP(myP, [](int * a) {
        *a = 8; // Custom deleter that is trying to dereference NULL never called
   }); 

   int a = 9;       
   myP = &a;

} // smartP goes out of scope, I expect custom deleter to be called
```

Comment: Isn't the deleter only called if the pointer is not null?

Comment: @melpomene Good call.  That is the answer.

Comment: _"If get() == nullptr there are no effects. "_ source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/~unique_ptr

Comment: With your edit, `myP` may not be null, but the pointer `smartP` has is still null.

Comment: @kevin if smartP takes ownership of myP, and myP is changed later, how smartP is still null? Looks confusing. Like smartP takes a copy of myP, and not myP itself

Comment: @siwmas `smartP` takes ownership of what `myP` points to, not `myP` itself. It's like this: `int i; int *a = NULL; int *b = a; a = &i; /* b is still NULL */`.

Comment: @Kevin Thnks, not it makes sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unique_ptr`'s destructor will only call its deleter if the contained pointer is not `nullptr`.

From N3337, [*[unique.ptr.single.dtor]*/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/unique.ptr#single.dtor-2)

> *Effects:* **If `get() == nullptr` there are no effects.** Otherwise `get_deleter()(get())`.

Comment: So I guess the question now is why get() == nullptr when myP changed in a later stage to actually point somewhere

Comment: @siwmas because the `unique_ptr` does not hold a *reference* to `myP` itself, but rather a *copy* of its value. The `unique_ptr` was constructed with a null pointer value. Changing the value of `myP` afterwards doesn't change the value of the pointer that `unique_ptr` holds internally. You would need to `reset()` the `unique_ptr` with a new pointer value when `myP` changes value, eg: `myP = &a; smartP.reset(myP);`